# Android soft keyboard - disable certain keys

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am looking for a way to use the built-in soft keyboard and disable certain key.
For example, if the User is not supposed to use the letter 'f' (because in the list, that letter is not present), the key should be grayed out.

Imagine that a User can type a text into a textbox for choosing from a list.

The list contains:

Abc
Bcd
Bed

If the User inputs:

-A

Then he will only be able to click on 'B' and then only to 'C'.

If the User inputs:

-B

At first he will be able to choose 'C' or 'E' and then according to the selection.

Is it possible without the need to create the keyboard from scratch?
If not, is there an easy way to make one? (I have found the one at developers.google.com)