# Android - is it possible to hide certain characters from the soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is it possible to hide (or disable) certain characters on the soft keyboard? It's been asked before: [Android soft keyboard - disable certain keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454368/android-soft-keyboard-disable-certain-keys) but no answer.

(I'd rather hide than disable keys but would go for either)
Thanks!

Comment: You have to build your own IME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to hide (or disable) certain characters on the soft keyboard?

Only if you create your own input method editor (a.k.a., soft keyboard) and get the user to switch to it.

Attributes like `android:inputType` are hints that some input method editors will honor and may control what characters are available. However, there is no guarantee that any given input method editor will honor it and what characters it will elect to include and exclude.

Comment: I disagree. I think it was a smart design decision. It prevents would-be malicious applications from trying to trick the user with phoney keyboards. While still leaving it possible to customize the keyboard...so long as the user agrees to it....Or the users carrier/manufacturer agreed to it for them =x.

Answer (score 1):

It can only be done if you create a 3rd party keyboard and the user selects it as the keyboard to be used on their device. I don't think you can customize the keyboard for within your own application very easily.