# Flutter : Keyboard without decimal point

Tags: flutter, dart, custom-keyboard

I need a numberInputKeyboard which only has numbers (without decimal symbol). I have tried with `keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: false)` but still this dosen't help me

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One answer recommends using a `BlacklistingTextInputFormatter` which certainly works in your case with English locale. This however might not work with other locales which use a `,` instead of a `.` as decimal seperator.

So I'd recommend using a [`WhitelistingTextInputFormatter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/WhitelistingTextInputFormatter-class.html):

```dart
import "package:flutter/services.dart";
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
)
```

This will only allows the digits `[0-9]`.

**UPDATE:**

The `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter` as been renamed! The following is the up-to date version and no longer deprecated by [`FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter/allow.html) and provides a shortcut for the digits as well:

```dart
import "package:flutter/services.dart";
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
)
```

Comment: Most Simpler.. Makes my work much easier..! Thank you Bro

Comment: This is cleaner as opposed to doing custom validations.

Answer (score 3):

BlacklistingTextInputFormatter and WhitelistingTextInputFormatter are deprecated. If you want to admit digits only, you could use:

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
```

If you want to admit numbers with decimal point:

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}')
```

Answer (score 2):

**First Approach** :-

As per this stackoverflow answer you must have to create your custom keyboard for it.

[Android - is it possible to hide certain characters from the soft keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536839/android-is-it-possible-to-hide-certain-characters-from-the-soft-keyboard)

**Second Approach** :-

You can do black list that stuff with `RegExp`, in this case you can't input dot(.).

For more you can refer this : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html

```
        body: Center(
            child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Title",
                suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                    setState(() {

                    });
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.clear),
                )),
            inputFormatters: [
               FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp("[.]")),
            ],
        )));
```

Comment: Great..! It works like charm.
But you have to import ```package:flutter/services.dart``` before using it.
Thank you..!!

Answer (score 1):

To aport this thread i did this, helped with the link provided by [Amit Prajapati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600058/amit-prajapati), its a but more manual but in my case worked perfectly

```
inputFormatters: [
          TextInputFormatter.withFunction((oldValue, newValue) {
            if (textInputType.decimal == true) {
              return newValue.copyWith(
                text: newValue.text.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\,"), "."),
              );
            }
            return newValue;
          }),
        ],
```

EDIT: `textInputType` is a variable for a custom TextField